# Wordpress Error "PHP missing MySQL extension required by WordPress"

Tags: raspbian, web-server

I am trying to create a lan web server using a LAMP configuration (linux, apache, mysql, and php)

I installed them using "sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php-mysql mysql-server"

They all worked fine.

Then, i decided to use WordPress to help me manage my lan web server
I did: sudo apt-get install wordpress, then, "sudo ln -s /usr/share/wordpress /var/www/html/wordpress" to link the directory and make it recognisable by the server.

Next, I did "sudo bash /usr/share/doc/wordpress/examples/setup-mysql - n wordpress localhost" to run the wordpress MySql configuration script.

Finally, i went to http://localhost/wordpress in a browser to install wordpress. There i got this error:

"Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

This was all done on Raspbian.

Comment: YES... It works. P.S. post that as a question next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the MySQL extension. You can do that with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd-ms
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart.
```